# does an rvis tutorial for complete and utter newbies exist?

Tags: ros, rviz, tutorial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Hydro and I have stepped completely through the set of Beginners Tutorials here:  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials
... so I have created and tested nodes, servers, messages, etc.

So now I would like to learn about the RVIS graphical user interface and create some very simple (sample or example or demo) robot software and use RVIS to visualize the robot in a simulation environment.  But I can't get through even the first RVIS tutorial:  http://wiki.ros.org/visualization/Tutorials

I've never even launched RVIS and don't know how to navigate it.  And this first tutorial doesn't introduce me to the GUI at all.  It directs me to the Users Guide in case I don't know RVIS:  http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide

The Users Guide is for the wrong version of RVIS, plus RVIS for me launches with an error saying that fixed frame [map] does not exist, so I can't do anything with that error and I don't know how to fix it.  Remember, I'm a complete newbie and I've never run RVIS before.

Please tell me someone out there has created a nice and simple RVIS newbie's tutorial that actually works and can be used to teach a newbie the basics of RVIS and teaches them in a way that parallels using it with an actual robot, so the transition from RVIS simulation to real robot is easy.

I don't have a robot yet, but I'd like to learn ROS and write some simple robot code and test that robot code using the visual simulation capability of ROS.  And I'm right now completely unable to do that.

Thanks for listening and thanks in advance for your answers.

Kurt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134401/does-an-rvis-tutorial-for-complete-and-utter-newbies-exist?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-28**:
The good news is using rviz with real or simulated robot is exactly the same. The catch is: Rviz does NOT do any simulation. Rviz only visualizes robot data. For simulation you'd need to use something like gazebo.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-28**:
Although the user guide seems outdated, rviz still works the same in principle. The most important sections would be 4 and 7 (in my opinion).

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-02-28**:
See, I told you I was a complete and utter newbie.  I thought RVIS was a visual simulator for ROS.  Something needs to be explained better on the ROS website so that newbies can fully understand the big picture.  I do not understand the big picture and I don't know how or where to learn it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-28**:
The last of the beginner tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WhereNext might be helpful. Usually you'd start a simulator + rviz and then do whatever you'd like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw the WhereNext tutorial, but it did not mention Gazebo.  It did mention a couple robot-specific simulators, though.  I totally missed the fact that Gazebo is what I need to use as a simulator to test my robot code on.  I for some reason thought that RVIS was intended to provide that functionality.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0